# disable keyboard battery notifications in 13.10

Tags: wireless, keyboard, battery, notification

I've updated to 13.10, and I'm getting notifications every hour or so that my wireless keyboard battery is low ... while it's sort of clever that Ubuntu can do this now and wants to show it off, a "low" wireless keyboard battery still lasts for weeks, and there's no apparent way to shut the notifications off... any help?